# Break iteration (each) in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Is it possible to break iteration in Svelte or limit like in angular (`ng-repeat="items in item | limitTo:4"`)?
For example:

```
{#each items as item, i}
  ...
  {#if i > 4}
    {:break}  <--- break here
  {/if}
  ...
{/each}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Svelte currently has no special syntax for breaks or ranges. ([here's a pending proposal](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2968)) A common idiom is to use a `{length: N}` object as the `#each` parameter, which usually performs better than creating new arrays every render.

`{#each {length: 4} as _, i} {items[i]} {/each}`

Here are some other patterns that work:

```html
<script>
    let items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    $: filteredItems = items.slice(0, 4);
    const filterItems = (i) => i.slice(0, 4);
</script>

<div>
    {#each {length: 4} as _, i}
        {items[i]}
    {/each}
</div>
<div>
    {#each items.slice(0, 4) as item}
        {item}
    {/each}
</div>
<div>
    {#each filteredItems as item}
        {item}
    {/each}
</div>
<div>
    {#each filterItems(items) as item}
        {item}
    {/each}
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no `{:break}` block, but you could [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) out the first 4 elements in the array before you iterate over it.

```
{#each items.slice(0, 4) as item, i} ... {/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use a `{#each myItems as item}{#if yourtruevalue} {item} {/if} {/each}` I don't know about the performance impact but it's very simple. if `yourtruevalue` is true - whatever the condition is for the item to render - it will render, and skip the item if not.